# Mantener ubicación en segundo plano Android

Tags: android, gps

Estoy buscando la forma de que una aplicación en segundo plano continúe trasmitiendo la ubicación a la base de datos y no se corte. He llegado al punto en el que se pone en segundo plano pero no envía ubicaciones.

Adjunto código, la clase `Main` y mi clase `Ubicacion`.

**Main**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "android-localizacion";

    private static final int PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION = 101;
    private static final int PETICION_CONFIG_UBICACION = 201;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient apiClient;

    private TextView lblLatitud;
    private TextView lblLongitud;
    private ToggleButton btnActualizar;

    private LocationRequest locRequest;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    public  String matricula = "test";

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:
                AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        lblLatitud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLatitud);
        lblLongitud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLongitud);
        btnActualizar = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btnActualizar);
        btnActualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleLocationUpdates(btnActualizar.isChecked());
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        UbiServ.class));
            }
        });

        //Construcción cliente API Google
        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                 user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


                if (user != null) {
                    matricula = user.getDisplayName();



                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ok, ja estàs loggetjat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder().setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setAvailableProviders(
                                            Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),

                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()
                                            ))
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);

                }
            }


        };
    }



    private void toggleLocationUpdates(boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            enableLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            disableLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    private void enableLocationUpdates() {

        locRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locRequest.setInterval(2000);
        locRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest locSettingsRequest =
                new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                        .addLocationRequest(locRequest)
                        .build();

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        apiClient, locSettingsRequest);

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Configuración correcta");
                        startLocationUpdates();

                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        try {
                            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Se requiere actuación del usuario");
                            status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, PETICION_CONFIG_UBICACION);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            btnActualizar.setChecked(false);
                            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Error al intentar solucionar configuración de ubicación");
                        }

                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Log.i(LOGTAG, "No se puede cumplir la configuración de ubicación necesaria");
                        btnActualizar.setChecked(false);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void disableLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                apiClient, this);

    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Ojo: estamos suponiendo que ya tenemos concedido el permiso.
            //Sería recomendable implementar la posible petición en caso de no tenerlo.

            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Inicio de recepción de ubicaciones");

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    apiClient, locRequest, MainActivity.this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        //Se ha producido un error que no se puede resolver automáticamente
        //y la conexión con los Google Play Services no se ha establecido.

        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error grave al conectar con Google Play Services");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        //Conectado correctamente a Google Play Services

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION);
        } else {

            Location lastLocation =
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);

            updateUI(lastLocation);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //Se ha interrumpido la conexión con Google Play Services

        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Se ha interrumpido la conexión con Google Play Services");
    }

    private void updateUI(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {
            lblLatitud.setText("Latitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
            lblLongitud.setText("Longitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
            saveLocation(loc);
        } else {
            lblLatitud.setText("Latitud: (desconocida)");
            lblLongitud.setText("Longitud: (desconocida)");
        }

    }

    public void saveLocation (Location loc)
    {
        myRef = database.getReference("root");
        Ubicacion last = new Ubicacion(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), loc.getTime());
        myRef.child(matricula).push().setValue(last);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                //Permiso concedido

                @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
                Location lastLocation =
                        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);

                updateUI(lastLocation);

            } else {
                //Permiso denegado:
                //Deberíamos deshabilitar toda la funcionalidad relativa a la localización.

                Log.e(LOGTAG, "Permiso denegado");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Estàs autenticat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                  //  matricula = user.getDisplayName();

                else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Adeu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case PETICION_CONFIG_UBICACION:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.i(LOGTAG, "El usuario no ha realizado los cambios de configuración necesarios");
                        btnActualizar.setChecked(false);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Recibida nueva ubicación!");

        //Mostramos la nueva ubicación recibida
        updateUI(location);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Ubicacion Service**

```
public class UbiServ extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        LocationListener {
    private static final String LOGTAG = "android-localizacion";

    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient apiClient;

    private TextView lblLatitud;
    private TextView lblLongitud;

    private LocationRequest locRequest;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    public String matricula = "test";

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio ONCREATE ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate();


       /* mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


                if (user != null) {
                    matricula = user.getDisplayName();

                    Toast.makeText(UbiServ.this, "Ok, ja estàs loggetjat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }


        };
        */
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio arrancado ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        this.mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        matricula = this.mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
        //Construcción cliente API Google
        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        //Conectado correctamente a Google Play Services

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

           /*ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION);*/
        } else {
            enableLocationUpdates();

            Location lastLocation =
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);

            updateUI(lastLocation);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //Se ha interrumpido la conexión con Google Play Services

        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Se ha interrumpido la conexión con Google Play Services");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //Se ha producido un error que no se puede resolver automáticamente
        //y la conexión con los Google Play Services no se ha establecido.

        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error grave al conectar con Google Play Services");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Recibida nueva ubicación!");

        //Mostramos la nueva ubicación recibida
        updateUI(location);
    }

    private void updateUI(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {
            lblLatitud.setText("Latitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
            lblLongitud.setText("Longitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
            saveLocation(loc);
        } else {
            lblLatitud.setText("Latitud: (desconocida)");
            lblLongitud.setText("Longitud: (desconocida)");
        }

    }

    private void toggleLocationUpdates(boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            enableLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            //disableLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    private void enableLocationUpdates() {

        locRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locRequest.setInterval(2000);
        locRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(UbiServ.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Ojo: estamos suponiendo que ya tenemos concedido el permiso.
            //Sería recomendable implementar la posible petición en caso de no tenerlo.

            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Inicio de recepción de ubicaciones");

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    apiClient, locRequest, UbiServ.this);
        }
    }

    public void saveLocation(Location loc) {
        myRef = database.getReference("root");
        Ubicacion last = new Ubicacion(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), loc.getTime());
        myRef.child(matricula).push().setValue(last);
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es decir que ¿a veces las envía y a veces no?

Comment: @Huntzberger No..nunca envia en segundo plano...

Comment: ya lo depuró? para saber en donde se corta?

Comment: @Huntzberger No se corta...simplemente creo que falta algo poner para que la mande...y no se el que.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no se van a enviar actualizaciones de geolocalización ya que al enviar a segundo plano tu aplicación estas removiendo el listener:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}
```

te sugiero remover el anterior mètodo y también el método en el cual vuelves a registrar el listener:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}
```